# A grammar question on integrals

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Let's say I wrote an integral in equation (1) for instance. Is the following sentence has grammatical errors in the perspective of mathematics and english language:

" Substituting $x^{2} = t \rightarrow 2x \, dx = dt $ then $t = y^3 \rightarrow dt = 3y^2 \, dy $ in the
integral in equation (2), gives... "

If the question is not suitible for this site, ı will immediately delete the question in the direction of your comments. Thank you!

Comment: I think the arrows are kind of unusual in text. I would write something like,"Substituting $x^2=t$ (so $2xdx = dt)$ and then $t=y^3$ (so $dt=3y^2dy)$ in the ... ," but this is more a matter of taste than grammar.  It's just that the way it's written, I had to stop for a second and figure out what you were saying.

Comment: It's readable and unambiguous, and that's normally the only criterion I apply. I wouldn't use the arrows in a formal paper or a set of lecture notes - I'd use words instead - but I might use squiggly arrows or something in rough working or on a blackboard.

Comment: I can understand exactly what the sentence says (assuming it makes sense with regards to what equations (1) and (2), of course), and it sounds right. I don't feel confident enough in my writing skills to say conclusively whether the language is correct though.

Comment: You might say: “From equation (1), we obtain equation (2) by making two successive substitutions: first, $x^2=t$ (so $2x\,dx=dt$), and second, $t=y^3$ (so $dt=3y^2\,dy$).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrow, $\text{“}\longrightarrow\text{''}$ is used in calculus in such statements as $f(x) \to L$ as $x\to a.$

It is used in many mathematical contexts, where $P\longrightarrow Q$ means "If $P$ then $Q.$"

And it is used in things like $f:A\to B.$

And it's probably used in some other commonplace contexts that are not occurring to me just now.

It is also used by confused students to mean something like "The next step after that is..." or as a catch-all when they don't know what else to use.

I wouldn't use it in the way in which you've used it.

I might write:

"Substituting $x^2 = t,$ so that $2x\,dx = dt,$ and also $t=y^3,$ so that $dt = 3y^2\,dy$, in equation $(2),$ gives..."

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Hardy, I have another question. Do you think writing the part "in the integral" is true?

Comment: @BrightChancellor : That part looks ok as nearly as I can tell without more context.